# How to Perform True False Comparison on Two different array values

Tags: php, arrays, comparison

I have two arrays:

```
$array_one = array(1=>6000,2=>500);
$array_two = array(1=>6500,2=>250);
```

I would like to compare the values with `>` or `<` like this:

```
if(6000 > 6500){
    echo "ok";
}else{ echo "not allowed";}

if(500> 250){
    echo "ok";
}else{ echo "not allowed";}
```

How can I perform this type of operation using a loop or something else?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You access array values using the square bracket notation `[index]`, therefore you can simply reference the values using their index;

```
if($array_one[1] > $array_two[1]) {
    echo "ok";
}
else {
    echo "not allowed";
}
```

and then you can put that in a loop, like this;

```
for($i=1;$i<=count($array_one);$i++) {
    if($array_one[$i] > $array_two[$i]) {
        echo "ok";
    }
    else {
        echo "not allowed";
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks this is useful for me ! but I want to know how to perform this using jquery ?

Comment: Your code is in PHP. Have you got jquery (or just javascript) code already?

Comment: Sir Can I post another question for Jquery Code  or edit this question?

Comment: By all means. Leave this question as it is, and ask a new one.

Comment: @RammeharSharma As you have yet to accept an answer on any of your questions, if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark on the left of the answer. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: when I vote up the answer a message "requires 15  reputation" is highlighted

Comment: You can still accept an answer before you reach 15 reputation.

Comment: Thank u very much Sir. I am very happy for your help. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

```
   <?php

    foreach($array_one as $key => $value) {
        if($value > $array_two[$key]) {
            echo "OK";
        } else {
            echo "Not Allowed";
        }
    }

   ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$array_one = array(1=>6000,2=>500);
$array_two = array(1=>6500,2=>250); 

foreach($array_one as $k => $v)
{
    if($v > $array_two[$k]){
    echo "ok";
    }else{ echo "not allowed";}
}
```